# Calculating the possible number of configurations

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, hyperparameter, combinatorics, bayesian-optimization

I am wondering how did they get the $19200$ possible configurations? Like, $5^6 = 15625$, where $6$ is the number of hyper-parameters:

[image]

ps: just to check I'm doing the righ thing. Is this okay?
The formula is $[a,b]: b -a + 1$. So in the second screenshot, the total number would be $31 \times 71 \times 71\ \times\ 9 \times 9 = 12.657.951$ possible configurations?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each hyper parameter listed has $5,5,6,4,4,8$ different values listed. If multiplied, total number of combinations make $5\times5\times6\times4\times4\times8=19200$.

Comment: Thank you very much! They are including the values from the extremes i.e., [2,7], 2 and 7 are included.

Comment: Yes, typically brackets $[,]$ means the boundaries are included.

Comment: This would apply? In a closed interval $ 
 [a,b]$, the number of integers is $
 b-a+1$.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct formula.

Comment: I have updated the OP with a new screenshot. Is it okay?

Comment: For the first three, it seems correct but I couldn't be sure if $\log \mathcal U$ represents an integer range with boundaries included. For the fourth and fifth options, the range is not integer, so you cannot apply the formula.

Comment: For integer variables the generated values in logarithm domain are transformed back and rounded to the nearest integer

Comment: I don't get what you mean. You need to specify what $\log U(20,30)$ means.

Comment: Check the updated OP. I added another screenshot

Comment: This is different than your original question. if the range represented by $U$ or $\log U$ is not an integer range like in $U(0.001, 0.009)$, number of possible combinations without specifying a step size is infinite. Bayesian optimization is a clever way of choosing informative hyperparameters over such a large range of possibilities.

Comment: Such a good answer. Should I consider reducing the number of possibilities?

Comment: It's always good to be able to reduce the number of possibilities, or ranges if you have continuous variables. Bayesian HPO can do better in short time if you do.

Comment: Indeed there has to be a threshold or something related because I haven’t encountered any research paper where they state that you should limit the number of possibilities in Bayeasian a optimization